# Stop method execution and wait for event?

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, servlets

I have a backing method that should be stopped in between the execution and should wait for a specific `flag` to be set or `event` to occur.

Currently I am just `polling` to an `application-scoped variable`. If it gets set by any other request then the waiting method may continue.

But is `polling` the proper way, or are there better?

Comment: I guess the signal comes from another thread?

Comment: no from another servlet. i am not creating threads manually.

Comment: Ok, but servlets run on their own thread right?

Comment: @membersound another servlet is actually another thread

Comment: ok thanks for this info. then yes it comes from another thread

Comment: How do you trigger the polling, by firing an HTTP request or by iterating in a loop?

Comment: by a loop that is triggered or started on a button click

Comment: So all this is happening on the server-side?

Comment: yes everything is processed on the server

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Hopefully I understood this right. Polling is inefficient as it wastes CPU cycles. You can use an object as a signal:

```
Object signal = new Object();
volatile boolean shouldWait = true;
```

in the waiting method:

```
// ...    
synchronized(signal) {
   while(shouldWait) {
      signal.wait();
   }    
}
```

in the signalling code:

```
synchronized(signal) {
   shouldWait = false;
   signal.notify();
}
```

Comment: shouldWait must be volatile. Also how will you tell one Servlet to update one variable in another (I have one idea, but would like to hear yours also)?

Comment: @Eugene: Can't you have a global variable that both servlets see? Like the one he was using to poll in the initial version. Thanks for the `volatile` btw.

Comment: sure you are right, but defining *global* in case of Servlets that are ment to be stateless is not that easy. If by global you mean ServletContext...

Comment: @Eugene: I guess the OP abandoned the idea of stateless from the beginning. :)

Comment: @Eugene: I guess at this point I was just thinking of having these shared variables as static somewhere. I know it's probably the worst idea but his scenario doesn't seem to be very common either.

Comment: I do agree, but don't static are one per class loader? If the servlets were loaded by different... ServletContext is the idea I had :)

Comment: @Eugene: Yes I was also thinking about that. I guess the OP should just use what worked for him before.

Answer (score 2):

I would suggest to use [Observer](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Observer_pattern) pattern where the first servlet would be an [observer](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Observer.html) of the object that implements [Observable](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Observable.html). When something happens, the second servlet would update the observable, and calls the setChanged() method which in turn would notify the observers (your first servlet in this case).